# Using the valgrind massif tool, Result file not created

Tags: c++11, memory-leaks, valgrind, heap-memory, massif

I have been following this tutorial for reference:
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

When I am using it to profile my Application Using the command:
valgrind --tool=massif --time-unit=B ./run.o
It finishes but does not produce any output file.
Here is the log while running it using the mentioned command.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yae78rm9wmdbph1/ValGring_massif_Log?dl=0

Kindly suggest why it won't produce a massif.out.xxxxx file ?

Answer (score 2):

If you look in your log file you will see that Valgrind has
crashed, and it explains why, and what you should do to fix it.

```
valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:304 (get_bszB_as_is): Assertion 'bszB_lo == bszB_hi' failed.
valgrind: Heap block lo/hi size mismatch: lo = 91849568, hi = 1425748016.
This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.
```

Use Valgrind's [`memcheck`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) to fix
your program and try again.